# how to upload file using android phonegap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I created application using android phonegap. I want to upload file ((i.e. when I click upload button file selection dialog box will open, then I select the file then click open button in that dialog.)

I use file transfer in phonegap API but the output is not like that. How to modify that file transfer in phonegap API to choose file (open dialog, choose file from that dialog) for upload?

And also I use `<input type="file">` from html. But it is not supported by phonegap The output is choosefile-button is displayed but when I click on that button nothing happens.

How I will open filedialog and choose file from dialog when clicking the button?

Please guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap Plugins are the way to go.

There are fileuploader plugins out in the git repo that you can use.

Here's links to the iPhone and Android plugins:

[iPhone File UPloader](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/FileUploader)

[Android File UPloader](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/FileUploader)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I use android file uploader.But in logcat I got an error "window.plugins.fileuploader is not an object".Please give step by step procedure for use that plugin.and another doubt is this plugin open the dialogbox for choose a file,In .html file which coding I will use(give an example code-use in html).I want to attach audio/video using android phonegap.please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mercy hi did you got any solution for this question? If so can you please share me? Thank you

Comment: Link's dead, any chance we can update the links here?

Answer (score 0):

The above answer should help you. I got also a similar problem with you, it is solved as I put the fileuploader.js inside the asset/www/ folder and give a reference to it in the index.html file.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [post](http://opensourcesoftwareandme.blogspot.com/2012/08/attaching-file-in-cordova-uploading-it.html). It points to an example on GitHub which shows how to attach a file in PhoneGap using `<input type="file">` and upload it using jQuery Mobile.